# Android HLS- Streaming failed to fetch segment

Tags: android, streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I write a Videoplayer for Android to stream Video over HLS. On my Server I have the m3u8-Playlist and the .ts-Segments.
My Code look like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);
}


public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(vidAddress);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Player works fine for the Apple bipbopall.m3u8 example. But when I try to play my Playlist this error occurs:

```
E/PlaylistFetcher﹕ failed to fetch .ts segment at url 'http://example.com/USSM.mp4Frag1Num0.ts'
E/LiveSession﹕ XXX Received error -1008 from PlaylistFetcher.
E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1008)
```

I think there is a problem with the AES-128 decryption of the files. Does the MediaPlayer decrypt the files by him self and how can I check if the decryption was successful? (I use the latest Android-Version)

Comment: `1008` is an `ERROR_OUT_OF_RANGE` when trying to fetch the file. What does your playlist look like?

Comment: @aergistal
`#EXTM3U`  
`#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0`  
`#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO`  
`#EXT-X-VERSION:2`  
`#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="/hls-vod-enc-key/hlscf.key",IV=0X99b74007b6254e4bd1c6e03631cad15b`  
`#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8`  
`#EXTINF:8,`  
`USSM20000051_abr-100.mp4Frag1Num0.ts`  
`#EXTINF:8,`  
`USSM20000051_abr-100.mp4Frag1Num1.ts`  
`#EXTINF:8,`  
`USSM20000051_abr-100.mp4Frag2Num2.ts`  
`#EXTINF:8,`  
`USSM20000051_abr-100.mp4Frag3Num3.ts`  
`#EXT-X-ENDLIST`

Comment: MediaPlayer is able to decrypt the files. HLS supports `AES` since v1 and Android is able to use v2 on 3.x and v3 on 4.x. You can try the same stream in the VLC Android app (not the beta) and see if it works. You can also enable a debug log in it.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be an error on the Apache Server.
But I can stream a mp4- File and I do everything what is discribed to configure my Webserver. "No custom server modules are required to deliver the content, and typically very little configuration is needed on the web server. Recommended configuration is typically limited to specifying MIME-type associations for .M3U8 files and .ts files."(Apple Developer HLS)

Comment: `mp4` files are streamed differently using progressive download. To check the encryption use `openssl` and try to decrypt one of the segments with the provided key and iv. The algorithm used is `aes-128-cbc `.

Comment: I tried it with a file without any encryption and the same error occurs

Comment: The `.ts` segments are in a mp4 container. This file can be played  e.g. with the VLC-Player

Comment: That can't be right because the `.ts` is also a container format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resume the discussion in the comments:

`1008` is `ERROR_OUT_OF_RANGE` returned when trying to read the segment into a buffer. Check if the server is properly responding by downloading a segment, decrypting it and attempting to play it back (see method below).

Other things to check: make sure the `MPEG-TS` segments are valid. If you used the `H.264` stream contained in an `MP4` file to create the segments check if they're using the `Annex B` format (for eg. in `ffmpeg` you can use the `h264_mp4toannexb` bitstream filter which works on the encoded stream - you can use it with `-c:v copy`)

To check if the encryption is correct use `openssl`.

1. Get the key in plain hex

   `xxd -p keyfile.key`
2. Decrypt a `.ts` segment

   ```
   openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in encrypted_segment.ts -out decrypted_segment.ts -nosalt -iv <iv_hex> -K <key_hex>
   ```

   If there's no defined IV then it is equal to the media sequence.
3. Attempt to play back the decrypted segment.