# "does not contain any stream" if "EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE" > 0

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a list of .ts files and want to save them as multiple video files.

---

First I have a .m3u8 like this obtained from streaming:

```html
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="aaa001_00001.key"
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00002.ts
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00003.ts

...

#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_01944.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

---

Step 1:

So, I tried to convert it into several m3u8 like the followings:

segment1.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="aaa001_00001.key"
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00002.ts
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00003.ts

...

#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00569.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

segment2.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:567
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="aaa001_00001.key"
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00002.ts
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00003.ts

...

#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_01288.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

and so on...

then do the ffmpeg cmd one by one..

> ffmpeg -i /fs/segment2.m3u8 -safe 0 -map 0:v -map 0:a -cpu-used 4 -threads 0 -preset veryfast -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4

---

But those EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE > 0 (i.e. since segment2.m3u8...) will result in

> "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

---

Then I tried to make the 'segment2.m3u8' looks like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="aaa001_00001.key"
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00002.ts <--the first video chunk
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00570.ts <--the start point of segment 2
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00571.ts

...

#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_01288.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

---

ffmpeg works fine, and gives me an output video, so it seems the stream channel info is in the first chunk.

However, there are still several problems

1. the first chunk of video is in segment2.mp4 which I clearly do not want it here.
2. the segment2 output video plays first the 3.01s, then freezed the image  until the time reach aaa001_00570.ts and play again

---

So, any suggestion so that I can reference the stream info from first chunk? or ignore it in the playlist, etc?

---

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

As it works when #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0, and #EXT-X-KEY: IV =  by default

So I add IV=hex(#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE)in every playlist

segment1.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="aaa001_00001.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00002.ts
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00003.ts

...

#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00569.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

segment2.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:567
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="aaa001_00001.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000237
#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_00570.ts

...

#EXTINF:3.01,
aaa001_01288.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES-128 encryption/decryption requires a 16-byte initialization vector (IV). If the `IV` attribute is not specified in the `EXT-X-KEY` tag then it defaults to the `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE`.

Your problem is most likely caused by a wrong IV. You have to find the correct sequence number based on the number of entries in the playlist, the filenames of the segments are irrelevant.

You can use [openssl in CLI mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245608/android-hls-streaming-failed-to-fetch-segment/32254229#32254229) to test whether a segment is correctly decrypted.

Comment: ah.. so if the key works with #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0. What I need to do is to add a "IV:0x00000000000000000000000000000000" at the back of the line "#EXT-X-KEY" in "Step 1" playlist?